# Passing commands to a subshell with xargs does not work inside an alias

Tags: bash, alias, xargs, subshell

I was trying to build a quick script to find all the git repos under a directory and sequentially "git pull" each one.

This is what I found so far:

```
find ~/ -name ".git" -type d | sed 's,/*[^/]\+/*$,,' | xargs -L1 bash -c 'cd "$1" && git pull' _
```

If pasted into a terminal, this will work exactly as it's intended. However, if I make this into an alias in my `.bashrc` file:

```
alias gpa="find ~/ -name ".git" -type d | sed 's,/*[^/]\+/*$,,' | xargs -L1 bash -c 'cd "$1" && git pull' _"
```

The command doesn't work. I modified it in an attempt to get it to print what the subshell launched by xargs is receiving:

```
alias printgpa="find ~/ -name ".git" -type d | sed 's,/*[^/]\+/*$,,' | xargs -L1 bash -c 'echo "$1"' _"
```

When run, each subshell prints a newline, but nothing else.

Can anyone answer why this is happening? My gut feeling says that it's a problem with my syntax in the alias, but I don't know exactly what's going on.

Comment: `set -x` in bash will get it to echo the commands as it sees them, just before executing them. Great for sorting out tricky quoting issues.

Comment: You probably want to use a function instead of an alias, so that you won't need to worry about tricky quoting to make it work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `$1` is getting substituted when you define the alias, rather than when you run it. To prevent that, you need to quote the `$`, either by using a backslash, or by using some single-quotes. For example:

```
alias printgpa='find ~/ -name .git -type d | sed '\''s,/*[^/]\+/*$,,'\'' | xargs -L1 bash -c '\''echo "$1"'\'' _'
```

Comment: Excelent! Thank you very much, this works perfectly. My alias now says:


`alias gpa="find ~/ -name ".git" -type d | sed 's,/*[^/]\+/*$,,' | xargs -L1 bash -c 'cd "\$1" && git pull' _"`

Comment: @MartijnPieters: nice answer. the OP did not accept it, however +1 from me.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe it is easier to read when you use GNU Parallel:

```
alias gpa="find ~/ -name .git -type d | parallel 'cd {//} && git pull'"
```

Plus you get the added benefit of getting more gits to pull in parallel.

It takes literally 10 seconds to install GNU Parallel:

```
wget pi.dk/3 -qO - | sh -x
```

Watch the intro videos to learn more: https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL284C9FF2488BC6D1

Comment: +1 for Parallel, but wgetting a script to install a tool that is often simply available your OS' software repository feels a bit iffy. I'm not sure that it is a good idea to encourage people to execute scripts this way.